# CreateGHCiProcess failed with failed with error 0: The operation completed successfully

Tags: haskell

When I open WinGHCi the following error message pops up:

CreateGHCiProcess failed with failed with error 0: The operation completed successfully

I don't know how to fix this, It's my first time trying to do anything with Haskell, and I've already tried reinstalling the program.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Weird error, I'm unsure about how to debug that. Have you tried installing the "haskell platform"? It should contain all the needed tools for Haskell development.

Comment: That's where I got the program, exact spot was Haskell.org

Comment: It seems that the issue was a mechanical one, a different computer seems to run it just fine